# Integral of volume form over $S^2$

Tags: integration, geometry, differential-geometry

I need help to calculate the integral over $S^2$ of the cannonical volume form given by $\omega_p(u,v) = det(u,v,p) $ using only definitions of integral of forms in a orientable compact manifold. I have the integrable partition of the unity subordinated to the cover $\{S^2-\{N\}, S^2-\{S\}$} given by $\alpha_S=1$ in the closed north hemisphere and $\alpha_S=0$ in its complement and $\alpha_N=1-\alpha_S$. And know that the first step is:

$\int_{s^2} \omega = \int_{s^2}\alpha_S.\omega + \int_{s^2}\alpha_N.\omega $